# How to search n query multiple options from the filter n get data from mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, join, multi-select

My DB data is stored in Mongodb. Right now, my filters are querying and matching the exact match and getting data based on that query.

`?page=1&size=10&Destination_Country=India&State=&Eligible_Citizenship=&University=&Category=&Race_Ethnicity=&Sex=Male&Study_Area=&Program_Level=`

I need to implement multiple options in search so, that I can send multiple items in the query as I added in Destination Country "India,  United States"

`?page=1&size=10&Destination_Country=India, United States&State=&Eligible_Citizenship=&University=&Category=&Race_Ethnicity=&Sex=Male&Study_Area=&Program_Level=`

how do I use join or any other best possible solution so, that MongoDB fetches results matching multiple options

```
  user.filter = querystring.stringify(req.query);

const query = {
      ...(Eligible_Citizenship && { Eligible_Citizenship: { $regex: Eligible_Citizenship, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(State && { State: { $regex: State, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(Destination_Country && { Destination_Country: { $regex: Destination_Country, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(University && { University: { $regex: University, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(Program_Level && { Program_Level: { $regex: Program_Level, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(Study_Area && { Study_Area: { $regex: Study_Area, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(Sex && { Sex }),
      ...(Category && { Category: { $regex: Category, $options: "i" } }),
      ...(Race_Ethnicity && { Race_Ethnicity: { $regex: Race_Ethnicity, $options: "i" } })
    };
```

above is the current reference code.